# Why doesn't Mathematica show up in OS X Spotlight?

Tags: bugs, mac-os-x, installation

When I enter a string that matches part of the name of an application on Mac, the OS X [Spotlight](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18828?locale=en_US) search feature will suggest apps for me to launch. This works for *every* app *except* *Mathematica*:

[image]

While the string is recognized (presumably from my history) the application is not suggested, and the only way to launch it is directly from the Finder or some other awkward workaround.

Why would — indeed *how could* —  *Mathematica* behave differently in this regard? What can I do to restore this standard piece of functionality?

---

Note that this problem is unique to *Mathematica*. For example for JetBrains apps, I get:

[image]

Moreover, it extends to the Finder itself. For example if I search there I get

[image]

even though *Mathematica* is clearly there

[image]

I can reproduce this (for *Mathematica* only) by simply updating (download, open the DMG, drag the new version to the Applications folder, replace). This is indeed unique to *Mathematica* (in my experience). I update at least one app a day in this or similar ways, and none of them vanish as a result from Spotlight; only *Mathematica*.

---

UPDATE: An apparent solution to this problem is available [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/229777/4395), though the cause remains a mystery.

Comment: Mathematica shows in Spotlight on my Mac with Mac OS X 10.11.2

Comment: Works here too. Is it possible you just installed or updated the OS and spotlight hasn't had enough time to index the hard drive?

Comment: @bills: No. I waited for months. I'd hoped it would "reset" somehow with the latest OS X update, but it hasn't.

Comment: You can force spotlight to re-index: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716

Comment: "only way to launch it is directly from the Finder". You could put _Mathematica_ in the dock.

Comment: I used to have the same problem. I deleted the Spotlight cache, which forced it to reindex the system, and that fixed it. You should try bill s's solution, which seems like a more non-violent way of doing the same thing.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Well, sure. But I could also just type *p-y-t-h-o-n*.

Comment: @bills: That did the trick. Pleas add that as an answer and I'll accept (all I needed to do was do that for the Applications folder). I still wonder know MMA managed to exclude itself alone!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is unrelated to Mathematica and probably belongs to http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @shrx: That's not clear yet. It remains to be seen whether there's a reason this happened only to MMA and not to any other app, ever.

Comment: @shrx: Steps to reproduce: Update *Mathematica* from a previous version (download, open the DMG, drag the new version to the Applications folder, replace). This is indeed unique to MMA (in my experience): I update at least one app a day and *none* of them vanish as a result from Spotlight; only *Mathematica*.

Comment: @shrx: This remains a Mathematic specific issue that has resurfaced with the update to 11. Clearly (yet another!) Mathematica-specific bug.

Comment: @shrx: This continues to be a (reappearing) issue that's unique to Mathematica.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I think this should be reopened, since the issue occurs only with Mathematica, not other software.

Comment: @becko Agreed. I've never seen this with any other app, and see it regularly with Mathematica.

Comment: @shrx I think this should be reopened, as it is related specifically to Mathematica. See my previous comment.

Comment: This continues to be a bug unique to Mathematica with 11.3.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, sometimes spotlight fails to index things properly. You can force spotlight to re-index by following the steps [here](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716). You can re-index either the whole hard drive or just the desired folder (in this case, the Applications folder).

Comment: Note that now that this bug has reappeared (see edit to OP), this solution has stopped working.

Comment: Any idea why this (a) never happens with any other application and (b) is reproducible for *Mathematica* (a simple update will reproduce)?

Comment: The bug reappeared (again, uniquely to Mathematica) with the "upgrade" to version 11, and [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/229777/4395) fixed it again (for now).

Comment: Make sure you add/remove the Applications folder under Macintosh HD, not the Applications folder in your home folder. I did that and was confused for a minute before I realised my mistake. Anyway, probably better to just reindex Macintosh HD.

Comment: This is not working.